# JQuery Deferred - Add callback after chain defined

Tags: jquery, callback, promise, deferred

```
var $jobApplication = $.Deferred();
$jobApplication
  .progress( displayState )
  .done( acceptContract )
  .done( relocate )
  .fail( keepCalmAndDrinkWine );

function displayState(payload){
  console.log(payload.state);

  if (payload.job){
    $jobApplication.resolve(payload.job); 
  }
}

$jobApplication.notify({
  state: "shortlist"
});

$jobApplication.notify({
  state: "phone_interview",
  date: "2013-01-23"
});

$jobApplication.notify({
  state: "technical_interview",
  date: "2013-02-11"
});

$jobApplication.notify({
  state: "physical_interview",
  date: "2013-02-14"
});

$jobApplication.notify({
  state: "salary_negociation",
  job: {
    role: "Software Engineer",
    company: "BBC",
    starts: "2013-03-04"
  },
  date: "2013-02-14"
});


function acceptContract(jobOffer){
  console.log("Contract accepted with the following details: ");
  console.log(jobOffer);
}

function keepCalmAndDrinkWine(err){
  console.log("Too bad it did not work for this reason: %s ", err); 
}

function relocate(){
  console.log("Relocating (a new Promise ;-)) ");
}
```

This is my example for describe some problems which i having some trouble.

i want to add some callbacks to "acceptContract" function. When "acceptContract" runs my new callbacks runs right away.

As example my first solution is adding this codes.

```
acceptContract = $jobApplication.promise();

acceptContract.done(function () {
    console.log('call your mom')
}).done(function () {
    console.log('be happy')
})
```

This codes working but one glitch. Working after chain complete.

console:

This what i get:

```
phone_interview
technical_interview
physical_interview
salary_negociation
Contract accepted with the following details:
Object {role: "Software Engineer", company: "BBC", starts: "2013-03-04"} 
Relocating (a new Promise ;-))
call your mom 
be happy
```

This what i expect:

```
phone_interview
technical_interview
physical_interview
salary_negociation
Contract accepted with the following details:
Object {role: "Software Engineer", company: "BBC", starts: "2013-03-04"}
call your mom 
be happy
Relocating (a new Promise ;-))
```

Comment: to be clear, what did you expect to happen instead? what is the *"glitch"*? it's going to be a logic error, and if we don't know what your intended logic is then all we can say is working as intended.

Comment: I expect to happen my after callbacks run after the 
"Contract accepted with the following details:
Object {role: "Software Engineer", company: "BBC", starts: "2013-03-04"} "
this line.

Comment: Is that not what they're doing? they are running after the contact accepted callback. do you mean, before the relocating callback? because if you want that, you'll have to add your callbacks before you add the relocating callback. they are executed fifo.

Comment: {Post edited}
I don't understand this. What is the purpose of promise then. I want to add 'listener' to a function when it 'done'. But i don't want to break my chain.

Comment: Right, and that's exactly what you're doing. The thing is, the callbacks are added to an array, then the callbacks in teh array are executed when it is *"done"*, in the order in which they were added. In this case, you added relocating to the array ***before*** you added your new callbacks, that's why it happens first.

Comment: So i need to break the chain ha? If it is. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of abusing the promise pattern. Two points:

- The callbacks on a promise should not affect it's state. You're resolving it from a progress listener, instead the process that is notifying the deferred should trigger progress events and resolve the promise from itself.
- The order of callbacks is defined as FAFC (first attached - first called), however more notably callbacks must (should) not be dependent on each other. That's defeating the pure design and makes code less clean. Instead, if you want one action to happen after the other you should chain them with `then`, creating a new promise for "action executed after first promise" on which you then can attach listeners for the second action. Often this means the new promise is resolved with that result of the first action which the second action needs, in your case you only need temporal chaining without a value.

```
function applyForJob() {
    var application = $.Deferred();
    return {
        step: function(payload) {
            application.notify(payload.state);
            if (payload.job)
                application.resolve(payload.job);
        },
        promise: application.promise()
    };
}

var $jobApplication = applyForJob();
$jobApplication.promise
  .progress( console.log.bind(console) )
  .fail( keepCalmAndDrinkWine );

var acceptedContract = $jobApplication.promise
  .then(acceptContract)
  .then(function() {
      console.log('call your mom');
      console.log('be happy');
  });
acceptedContract.done( relocate );

$jobApplication.step({
  state: "shortlist"
});

$jobApplication.step({
  state: "phone_interview",
  date: "2013-01-23"
});

$jobApplication.step({
  state: "technical_interview",
  date: "2013-02-11"
});

$jobApplication.step({
  state: "physical_interview",
  date: "2013-02-14"
});

$jobApplication.step({
  state: "salary_negociation",
  job: {
    role: "Software Engineer",
    company: "BBC",
    starts: "2013-03-04"
  },
  date: "2013-02-14"
});


function acceptContract(jobOffer){
  console.log("Contract accepted with the following details: ");
  console.log(jobOffer);
}

function keepCalmAndDrinkWine(err){
  console.log("Too bad it did not work for this reason: %s ", err); 
}

function relocate(){
  console.log("Relocating (a new Promise ;-)) ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for good points. I am very new with promises. But i need to know how can i do what i want. In your code i cannot add any listener function  to "acceptedContract"  and run right away.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot add listener function"? Sure you can attach them to every promise you want.

Comment: I am realy messing something up. Can you give me an example please. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mskasal/fsEKF/2/

Comment: You mean you have a chain already and want to insert an action into it? You cannot do that other by having inserted a placeholder (function) which you fill in later (give arguments). However, you can always attach additional listeners to every step of the chain. Notice that they might fire after the next step has already begun, which is crucial in your case of synchronous steps. If the tasks were asynchronous, the perceived order will change.